# Making One Unit Test Count as Several

Tags: .net, unit-testing

Using Visual Studio Test Suite, is there a way to make a single unit test behave and give results as if it were several tests?

I would like to have a test for each set of input parameters I will provide.  But I'd rather have all the varieties of input be data-driven, rather than having to write a seperate test for each one.

This question is [similar to this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910654/unit-testing-several-different-results-in-one-method) except that (1) I'm not using NUnit and (2) I might prefer my test data comes from a file (a file having data representing many tests).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to RowTest with MSTest ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/347535/how-to-rowtest-with-mstest)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSTest doesn't have the RowTest as in other xUnit frameworks. However it does seem to have a feature for [data-driven tests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182519.aspx) (that get their data from a DB/Xml/Csv file.) Its a case of simple things aren't possible... complex things are.

Actually this question might be a dupe of
[MSTest Equivalent for NUnit's Parameterized Tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367033)
[How to RowTest with MSTest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347535)

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered putting the actual test *code* in a separate, private method with parameters, then create multiple test methods that each just pass different parameters into the private method?

Asserts and such will still work.

Even though it's a test assembly, you can still create whatever support classes and methods  you need to support your tests.

Answer (score 1):

Unit tests are classes.

They can be instantiated and subclassed.

A test can (and sometimes should) have a "fixture" -- a file of source data.